# How to reach Palpur-Kuno Wildlife Sanctuary and does it offer accommodation?

Tags: india

How to reach Palpur-Kuno Wildlife Sanctuary in Madhya Pradesh from Shivpuri, Madhya Pradesh?

Is there accommodation there?

Comment: Reach from shivpuri

Comment: Yes that is rgt

Answer (score 1):

The Kuno Wildlife Sanctuary, in the Central India state of Madhya Pradesh, is nestled between the Agra-Mumbai and Jhansi-Shivpuri roads. By its very nature and to protect its resources, such an area has limitations on access and development. Not only is it 344,686 square kilometres, a surrounding 900 square kilometres serve as a protective buffer zone.

This [sanctuary is situated at Vijaypur and Sheopur tehsils in Sheopur district](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheopur). It is 15 km. from the Sesaipura bus stand on Shivpuri-Sheopur road. It can be approached by bus or taxi from Sesaipura bus stand. It can also be approached from Pohari of district Shivpuri at the distance of 25 km. Directly from Shivpuri, you would need a taxi for the 27 km to the sanctuary; one way would be about 400-480 INR and take about 30 minutes.

As @pnuts has noted, accommodations are not available currently within the sanctuary; you would have to return make arrangements in a nearby location.